# How to add required in QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, qplaintextedit

I want to add required in my QPlainTextEdit so that when there is a blank QPlainTextEdit, the user will then be prompted that there is a blank input.

This is my sample code and I want to add required in that QPlainTextEdit.

```
self.plainTextEdit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 251, 31))      
self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("txtName"))
```

Thanks for some answer!.

Comment: Do you want the QPlainTextEdit to have a placeholder that indicates that it is necessary that the QPlainTextEdit should not be empty with any message?

Comment: I want that if the user will submit it, if there is a blank QPlainTextEdit, the user will prompt.

Comment: Hello Nikko and welcome to the Stack-Overflow community. Please make sure that you are 'crystal-clear' as to what your question is, so that people reading your post can easily understand it and help you!

Comment: @NikkoJamesSantillan You have confused me more, explain yourself better. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You can have some code like this:

```
def on_submit(self, text): #set this to trigger once the user has submitted their text
    if text == "":
        print("You must enter some text") #or any other method of prompting the user
    else:
        self.text = text #or any other variable you want the text to be stored to
```

Pretty self-explanatory. I can provide an example program if you wish.

Hope this helps.